# Error during momepy.preprocess while generating tessellation based on OpenStreemap

Tags: geopandas, osmnx

I am working through the Morphological Measuring in Python (momepy) toolkit tutorial and have run into a problem when I step away from the instructions slightly.

When using momepy.preprocess, I have consistently been returned the error
"ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable."

This only occurs when I try to run momepy.preprocess on an area different than the tutorial - so far that includes Champaign, Urbana, and Peoria, Illinois, USA; Oxford, England; and Jena, Germany.  When run on Kahla, Germany (the location featured in the tutorial), the process runs correctly. The osmnx process of pulling the afore mentioned cities seems to work correctly, as does plotting them via plt.subplots. Therefore, I am reasonably confident the problem originates with momepy.preprocess.

The documentation states that momepy.preprocess is "experimental," but due to my own inexperience and lack of expertise, I suspect the problem is mine.

Thank you in advance for any assistance given - I'm very excited about learning more about this powerful set of tools!

Comment: Hi, can you report it to https://github.com/martinfleis/momepy/issues? I'll need a bit more information to figure out the issue (your code, the full error message at least).

Comment: Dr. Fleischmann, thank you very much for your prompt reply!

In the process of pulling things together to submit to the github page you provided, I also posed the question to my professor. After some digging, he uncovered that I needed to ensure that the geodataframe only contained Polygons - that sometimes OSM may return non-polygon elements. 

This was indeed the issue. I stripped out the non-polygon features with the line of code below and the rest of the process worked as expected.

gdf_poly = gdf_projected.loc[gdf_projected.geometry.type=='Polygon',:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geodataframe fed into momepy.preprocess can contain only polygons. Sometimes OSM returns non-polygon elements in the "buildings" layer. Extracting the polygons from the original geodataframe solved the problem, but in order to avoid removing MultiPolygon geometries which may be valuable, you should use `explode` before doing so. It is likely necessary to `reset_index` after using `explode` and extracting the polygons due to a bug in geopandas.

*Note: the reset index function returns a new GeoDataFrame, it doesn’t alter the original one, so you need to assign it back.*

Here is how my code ended up looking:

```
#Get building geometries from OSM
gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_place('Main Quad, Champaign,Illinois', tags={'building':True}, buffer_dist=1000)

gdf_projected = ox.projection.project_gdf(gdf)

#Explode muti-part geometries into multiple single geometries. 
gdf_exploded = gdf_projected.explode()

#Strip out polygons from exploded gdf
gdf_exploded_poly = gdf_exploded.loc[gdf_exploded.geometry.type=='Polygon',:]

#Reset index
gdf_exploded_poly = gdf_exploded_poly.reset_index()

#Run momepy.preprocess
buildings = momepy.preprocess(gdf_exploded_poly, size=30, compactness=0.2, islands=True)
```

Comment: I am afraid that will also remove some MultiPolygon geometries you may want to keep. It would be better to use `explode` before this step to ensure all MultiPolygons are turned into Polygons (note that you may need to reset index before that due to a bug in geopandas).

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you! I will edit the answer to reflect the change.